# how to enable combobox by selecting the radiobutton using jsp

Tags: jsp

I have two drop down lists with the names meterid and subzone and also i have 2 radio buttons in my application.If the user selects radio button1 , meterid dropdown list should be displayed. If the user selects radio button2, subzone dropdown list should be displayed. i will get the dropdown values from mysql tables.

i tried the following code:

```
function select1()
```

{ 
document.getElementById("meter_id").style.display="block"; document.getElementById("subzone_list").style.display="none";
}

```
function select2() {
     document.getElementById("subzone_list").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("meter_id").style.display="none";             
    }  

    document.getElementById("midradio").onclick = select1;
    document.getElementById("subzonerd").onclick = select2;

    </script>
    The following code is for Meterid dropdown lisT:
    <tr><td  width="15%" class="options0" id="tdSearchBy" colspan="5">

    <input name="r1" value="MeterID" onclick="" type="radio" id="midradio"><font size="4">Meter ID</font></td>

    <%
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suwatermeter","root","sumith");
        sqlQuery="select distinct Meterid from Meter_List";
        st=con.createStatement();

         rs=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
    %>


    <td  width="20%" class="options0" colspan="5">
    <select style="WIDTH: 150px" selected="true" name="meterid" id="meter_id"  onChange="this.form.submit()" style='display:none;'>
    <option>Select Meter ID</option>
    <% while(rs.next()) {%>
    <option value="<%=rs.getInt("MeterID")%>"><%=rs.getInt("MeterID")%></option>

    <% } 

    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
    %>

    </select>

    </td></tr>
    The following code is for Subzone dropdown list:
    <tr><td class="options1" id="tdSearchBy" colspan="5">

    <input name="r1" value="Subzone"  onclick="searchOptions(3)" value="subzone" type="radio" checked="checked" id="subzonerd"><font size="4">Sub zone</font></td>

     <%

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/suwatermeter","root","sumith");

        String getZoneName=request.getParameter("zonelist");
        sqlQuery="select  distinct Subzone from Meter_List where Zone='"+getZoneName+"'" ;
        st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
    %>
    <td  width="20%" class="options0" id="tdSearchBy" colspan="5">
    <select style="WIDTH: 150px" name="subzonelist" id="subzone_list" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="SZ">Select a Sub Zone</option>


    <% while(rs.next()){ %>
        <option value="<%=rs.getString("Subzone")%>"><%=rs.getString("Subzone")%></option>



    <%  } 

    rs.close();
    st.close();
    con.close();
    %>
    </select>
```

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1. From your question it is not clear what is the problem. (expect that it's not working as you want)
2. It's a javascript problem and not a jsp problem, so the tag is wrong.
3. I think you have a problem where you are trying to get the elements by their ID before the DOM has completed loading.

   document.getElementById("midradio").onclick = select1;
   document.getElementById("subzonerd").onclick = select2;

you should put this two lines in the end of the HTML or in a function that is called after the DOM is ready read this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp

Your "subzonerd" input element has already an onclick function set in the html, that might create another problem later.

Comment: thanks for reply raanan.i tried what you said but i didn't get the result.actually myproblem is if i click on meterid radio button it should display the associated combobox.